# Sqlite parameter substitution: "OperationalError: near "(": syntax error"

Tags: python, sqlite

This code works for me until i put another parameter substitution in, specifically the one after "SET". Is there something simple im missing here? Any help or advice would be great!

```
for i, item in enumerate(items[0]):
    print item,number_sold[0][i],date
    c.execute("UPDATE stock SET (?) = (?) WHERE date IN (?)",[item,number_sold[0][i],date])
    c.commit()
```

The error:

```
 ---> 51         c.execute("UPDATE stock SET (?) = (?) WHERE date IN   (?)",[item,number[0][i],date])
 52         c.commit()

OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

printing "item,number[0][i],date" gives me "Cake, 3, 735719.0" which is what I expect.

Comment: You can't parameterize column or table names. Only values.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Before I parameterised the column name I listed out each item one after another (each item having a column name) to update their values. I'm trying to get around this by having a loop to update the table for item in my list. Is there any pythonic way around this?

Comment: I'm not too sure if the duplicate answer solves my problem. I know now that you can't parameterize column or table names now, which is definitely a help. Is there a simple way for me to loop through each column name to update its value? @MartijnPieters

Comment: @Ciaran: why not update all columns in one?

Comment: The duplicate certainly answers your question *as posted*. You can use `   c.execute("UPDATE stock SET {} = (?) WHERE date IN (?)".format(item),[number_sold[0][i], date])` to interpolate a column name.

Comment: I have a list of items, that correspond to columns. The list comes in different orders and with items that are not in my database. It was just handy to loop through the list and use each items name to assign which column I want to update if the column exists. Granted I could sort out the list first, and then update them all at once. I was just hoping there was a way around it. Thanks for the help anyways :)

Comment: @Martijn Pieters the line you posted above works exactly as i needed. Saves me a lot of time typing out the different items, thanks! Could I just clarify for my understanding the ".format(item)" bit? Why do you need to use .format() and it knows thats what you want to put in the {} once you use it? Even a link to a good place to read about it would be great.

Comment: @Ciaran: the [`str.format()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) explains all. Yes, the `{}` is the placeholder that `.format()` fills.